# Locking a queue while re-ordering it in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, locking, queue

please consider the following:

- I have a queue of objects represented
  as an array.
- I process them off the top of the
  array (at position 1) before calling
  `arrayDeleteAt()` to remove it from
  the array.
- I add new queue item at the top of
  the array using `arrayAppend()`.

This works fine. However, I now wish to re-order the array immediately after adding an item.

I am concerned that if a thread is taking from the queue it will find the queue order has changed between it taking the item at position 1 and it deleting the item at position 1 - because in that time an additional item has been added the the queue has been re-sorted. So I need to ensure my queue is thread-safe.

Is there any way to doing this using the `cflock` tag? Since my add and remove code are in different places in the code the thread executing one bit of code would need to know that a thread is executing another specific bit of code and halt until that other thread has stopped executing it's code.

Or am I better off just raising a flag while the sorting is going on and preventing anything being taken from the array while the sort is in progress?

All this is happening in the `APPLICATION` scope on a CF 8 Enterprise server.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Ciaran

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An exclusive CFLOCK should do what you want. You could just scope-lock APPLICATION, but that might be overly broad. Probably best to do it as a named lock. It won't matter where the different bits of code with the lock are located, as long as they're all using the same name.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know what you could have more than one lock with the same name - I was really hoping this would be the case :)

Comment: @ciaranarcher: Better choose and unambiguous name. Named locks are server-wide!